# JCIFS NTLM Authentication for HTTP Connections on GlassFish (or any servlet container)

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish, ntlm, jcifs

I've created a Java class that connects to an IIS website requiring NTLM authentication. The Java class uses the JCIFS library and is based on the following example:

```
Config.registerSmbURLHandler();
Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.domain", domain);
Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.username", user);
Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.password", password);

URL url = new URL(location);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

The example works fine when executed from the command prompt, but as soon as I try to use the same code in a servlet container (specifically GlassFish), I get an `IOException` containing the message "Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: ....".

I've tried moving the jcifs jar to the system classpath (%GLASSFISH%/lib), but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that what I was trying to do is already supported in Java 5/6 and I was therefore able to drop the JCIFS API and do something like this instead:

```
public static String getResponse(final ConnectionSettings settings, 
        String request) throws IOException {

    String url = settings.getUrl() + "/" + request;

    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            System.out.println(getRequestingScheme() + " authentication")
            // Remember to include the NT domain in the username
            return new PasswordAuthentication(settings.getDomain() + "\\" + 
                settings.getUsername(), settings.getPassword().toCharArray());
        }
    });

    URL urlRequest = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlRequest.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    String str = "";
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(str);
    }
    in.close();

    return response.toString();
}
```

Comment: You are a fuc***ng genius. Saved my day. I love you.

Comment: That's not thread safe --- `Authenticator.setDefault()` sets the _global_ authenticator object...

Comment: @DavidGiven That's not helpful. Can you even set Authenticators per connection?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like JCIFS does not have the right to set a factory for handling your URLs inside Glassfish. You should check the policy settings (checkSetFactory).

The Config#registerSmbURLHandler() might swallow the SecurityException.

Comment: It doesn's seem like any Exception is being swallowed by Config#registerSmbURLHandler() (Source: http://jcifs.samba.org/src/src/jcifs/Config.java) as it only sets the java.protocol.handler.pkgs property to jcifs. I've tried adding the property to GlassFish's JVM options, but also without luck.

Comment: JCIFS registers an URLStreamHandler. That is not done inside the Config class. You have to look into the transport implementations inside the subordinated packages. So it still could be the security issue.